Accidentally remove pulseaudio Ubuntu 22.04
I was troubleshooting audio issues on my Ubuntu 22.04 system and followed a guide telling me to uninstall and reinstall pulseaudio. I did manage to uninstall it (apt remove, and a purge somewhere) but when trying to install it again I get an error that pulse audio package does not exist. apt suggested pulseaudio-utils , but that does not contain the server.
The error:

Package pulseaudio is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source However the following packages replace it: pulseaudio-utils

I've done all the usual updates et.c. "apt update"
What am I doing wrong? I find the package in the Ubuntu list of packages so it should exist, right?
Update
For some reason the apt sources for the default Ubuntu packages was only set to universal. Adding all other groups (or whatever they are called) solves the issue

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=pulseaudio
The pulseaudio package (with this exact name) definitely exiists in Ubuntu 22.04. I would guess your sources.list file is misconfigured. Please edit your question and add details about that too. If you can't fix that as a last resort you can download the package manually from Ubuntu, but without a correct sources.list you will run into similar issues again soon.

Not at the computer right now, but will update when I’m back home. I did have a look at the sources.list , most of it was commented out apart from last line stating something with CD/USB drive . All the commented sources had big warnings above them with do not remove comment, this is not supported . I can’t find a “template” file , what should it contain by default ?
